# Vue 3 modifying an element into a list using its index

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I´m storing the element´s index in a global variable. In the next code I can add various elements with the same properties, but I can´t edit none of them because it alters the rest. I´m trying to edit each one individually

I´m using vue-draggable-next (npm install vue-draggable-next) for drag and drop

And I´m using Sweetalert2 (npm install sweetalert2)

```
  <template>
  <head>
    <!-- Boxicons -->
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>

  <div class="container-fluid row mt-2">
    <div class="col-md-3 float-start">
      <div class="panel-default border" style="background-color: #f7f9fa">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
          <h3 class="panel-title visible-panel-text">Draggable elements</h3>
        </div>

        <!-- Elements zone -->
        <draggable
          class="row mt-2"
          :list="draggableElements"
          :sort="false"
          :group="{ name: 'cloneableItems', pull: 'clone', put: false }"
          @end="generateJSON"
        >
          <div
            class="col-sm-6 mb-2"
            v-for="element in draggableElements"
            :key="element.id"
          >
            <div class="border drag-element">{{ element.visibleName }}</div>
          </div>
        </draggable>

        <!-- Copy JSON panel -->
        <div
          class="panel-json json-container mt-2 border"
          style="background-color: #f7f9fa"
        >
          <div
            class="panel-heading text-center"
            @click="state.showJSONPanel = !state.showJSONPanel"
          >
            <h3
              class="panel-title"
              style="text-align: center; cursor: pointer; user-select: none"
            >
              JSON
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body" v-show="state.showJSONPanel">
            <textarea
              class="json-textarea form-control"
              v-model="state.generatedJSON"
              style="width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; resize: none"
            ></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" @click="copyJSON">
              Copy JSON
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <!-- Show content -->
      <draggable
        class="w-100 h-100 border"
        :empty-insert-threshold="1000"
        :list="state.contentElements"
        @update="generateJSON"
        :group="{ name: 'putItems', pull: 'clone', put: true }"
      >
        <div
          v-for="(element, index) in state.contentElements"
          :key="element.id"
          class="container"
        >
          <template v-if="element.type == 'description'">
            <label>This is the description element</label>
            <div>{{ element.descriptionText }}</div>
          </template>

          <!-- Edit & delete -->
          <div
            class="iterable-icons-container"
            style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end"
          >
            <!-- Edit icon -->
            <i class="bx bxs-cog edit-icon" @click="editElement(index)"></i>
            <!-- Delete icon -->
            <i class="bx bxs-trash-alt edit-icon" @click="deleteElement()"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </draggable>
    </div>

    <!-- Changes panel -->
    <div class="col-md-3 border">
      <div>
        <!-- Description -->
        <template
          v-if="
            state.editedIndex >= 0 &&
            state.contentElements[state.editedIndex].type == 'description'
          "
        >
          <label><strong>Description element</strong></label>
          <input type="text" v-model="edit.descriptionNewText" />

          <button class="btn btn-light" @click="saveChanges()">Save changes</button>
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

import { reactive, ref } from "vue";

//Drag and drop library
import { VueDraggableNext as draggable } from "vue-draggable-next";

//Sweetalert
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import "sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css";

//Array with the main elements list
const draggableElements = [
  {
    id: crypto.randomUUID(),
    visibleName: "Description",
    descriptionText: "This is a description that you can edit",
    type: "description",
    mandatory: false,
  },
];

//Variable where the data flows
let state = reactive({
  //Store a global index to edit
  editedIndex: ref(-1),
  contentElements: reactive([]),
  showJSONPanel: ref(false),
  generatedJSON: ref(""),
});

//eslint-disable-next-line
let edit = reactive({
  descriptionNewText: ref(""),
});

function copyJSON() {
  const textarea = document.querySelector(".json-textarea");
  textarea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  Swal.fire("Success", "JSON copied", "success");
}

function generateJSON() {
  //Actualizar valor del textarea
  let textarea = document.querySelector(".json-textarea");
  textarea.value = state.generatedJSON;

  //Generar el archivo JSON de acuerdo a lo puesto por el usuario
  state.generatedJSON = JSON.stringify(state.contentElements, null, 2);
}

//Edit
function editElement(index) {
  console.log("Button pressed");
  state.editedIndex = index;

  console.log("Index is: ", state.editedIndex)
}

//Delete element
//Eliminar elemento del panel de construcción del formulario
function deleteElement(index) {
  Swal.fire({
    title: "Confirm delete",
    text: "Are you sure?",
    icon: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete",
    cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      state.contentElements.splice(index, 1);
      state.generatedJSON = JSON.stringify(state.contentElements, null, 2);
    }
  });
}

//Save changes in the element
function saveChanges(type) {
  type = state.contentElements[state.editedIndex].type

  console.log("Type is: ", type)

  switch(type){
    case 'description':
      //Description data
      state.contentElements[state.editedIndex].descriptionText = edit.descriptionNewText;

      state.editedIndex = -1
      edit.descriptionNewText = ""
      break;
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.drag-element {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.edit-icon {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.edit-icon:hover {
  color: blueviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not use `index` as the unique key, in your case you need to use the `element.id` as the unique key;

```html
<i class="bx bxs-cog edit-icon" @click="editElement(element.id)"></i>
```